# does anyone have any recommendations on how to use qUnit with continuous integration, such as cruise control?

Tags: javascript, cruisecontrol, qunit

we're looking to do some unit testing with qUnit.  we use Cruise Control for continuous integration.  just curious if anyone has integrated qUnit in an automated fashion, and if so, what you did to get it all working...

Answer (score 1):

I set up a Jenkins CI to do this a while back, the way we did it was to write an NUnit test to run WatiN (selenium would work as well of course), that would then run the QUnit tests, with selectors to check for any errors and fail an assert for every test that failed. It's very important that you make sure you are testing in the correct browser due to differences in the javascript engines. For example, WatiN wouldn't work if you target platforms include Chrome because it can't control Chrome (last I checked).

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen the open source [NQUnit](https://github.com/robdmoore/NQUnit)? I haven't tried it yet but I plan on using it in an upcoming project.

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted but I wrote many QUnit tests and then used NQUnit to run them as a source of nunit test cases using the TestCaseSource attribute. Each QUnit test was displayed as an individual test case on our CI server.

Comment: Don't know either, Trystan. NQUnit works like a charm! I needed to retrofit it with Selenium to run Chrome and Firefox, but works well out of the box for IE10.